# codeigniter tpl {if} {else} documentation

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I'm trying to modify an application with codeigniter..

but the if else loop etc.. is not the default if else ex.:

```
{if isset($form1)}
{/if}

{foreach $data_ as $row}
{/foreach}

{cycle value="odd,event"}
```

where I can find a tutorial to learn this php particularity in template?

thanks!

Comment: Isn't this Smarty? [If else documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl)

Comment: yes. It's what I see now.. I the main url [smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/) thanks alot!